# [filename.exe]has stopped working in c programming IDE is Eclipse

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C programming, wrote a program for GCD in eclipse IDE as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, t;
    scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b);
    printf("GCD of %d, %d is", a, b);
    if (a < b) {
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    while (!(t==0) {
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t % b;
    }
    printf(" %d",a);
}
```

When Build All option is used its shows `Info: Nothing to build for g` and when I try to run the program it shows Filename.exe has stopped working.

I have restarted IDE as well the system but same error crops up again.

Comment: What's happening is that you are getting a *crash*. You should run in a debugger to locate the crash, my bet is that it will stop at the expression `t%b` with `b` being zero.

Comment: @Olaf, he may not know about `!=`, he is a beginner, as the OP states.

Comment: What is your *exact* input?

Comment: `while (t)` --> `while (b)`

Comment: @Olaf my issue is not code 't!=0' as I have already corrected that and forgot to edit here but the compiler, which gives error message and when it stop it gives me debug option but not always as per its will debug option is available so what is the resolution.

Comment: It certainly is not the compiler, but your IDE/build system. And that is not an error, but just a notice - read it carefully and try to understand, it is very clear. If I told to change your code, you didn't change anything (and even tell me), but I run the (previous version) of the code anyway, what would you expect to happen? Also note you might read an uninitialised variable (`t`), which is _undefined behaviour_, so all bets are off here, too. Your compiler should warn once you configured your builder correctly. Also **always** enable warnings and pay heed to them!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you have mentioned you are a beginner. let me explain.

This happens when your program crashes. It can be for various reasons. Normally you will have to use some debugging tool. But in this case, is simple as  "Joachim Pileborg" has mentioned in the comments.

You have to think about what happens when 'b' becomes zero. You are trying to divide something by zero. That is not mathematically possible. That's why your program crashes.

This has to do with basic mathematics, not programming.
[take a look](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221161514/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.divideby0.html)